# How do I see current seek position of an open file descriptor?

Tags: linux, file, awk, seek

I'm running an awk script on a 100G+ file. I have a suspicion that since it never finishes it got into some kind of infinite loop.

I want to see the line that script is currently at to see if there's some problem with the data.

I tried `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` but it just lists names of opened files.

Is there a way to find the current `seek` position of an open file?

Comment: Consider running GNU awk in debug mode, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is to use `strace -p <your pid>` to observe the running `pid`. An extension to `gawk` is created to call `lseek` from an awk script. `lseek` reports the file descriptor offset as you have requested.

You will need to modify the awk script to call the extension.

Without modifying the awk script, `strace -p <your pid>` will report lots of `read` calls and that usually indicates progress thru the input file.

Below is a Makefile to create the `lseek` extension and run a quick test.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -fPIC -c -O2 -DHAVE_STRING_H -DHAVE_SNPRINTF -DHAVE_STDARG_H -DHAVE_VPRINTF -DDYNAMIC
LDFLAGS = -shared 

all: awklseek.so
    gawk -l ./awklseek.so 'BEGIN{ print lseek() } { print $$0 ; lseek() ; } ' data

awklseek.so: lseek.o
    ${CC} $^ -o $@ ${LDFLAGS}

c.o:
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} $<

.PHONY:clean
clean:
    rm awklseek.so lseek.o
```

Here is the extension:

```c
/*
 * lseek.c - Provide an interface to lseek(2) routine
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include "gawkapi.h"

static const gawk_api_t *api;
static awk_ext_id_t ext_id;
static const char *ext_version = "lseek extension: version 1.0";
static awk_bool_t init_lseek(void);
static 
awk_bool_t(*init_func) (void)= init_lseek;

    int     plugin_is_GPL_compatible;

/* do_lseek --- implement the lseek interface */

    static awk_value_t *
            do_lseek      (int nargs, awk_value_t * result, struct awk_ext_func *unused)
{
    awk_bool_t  api_result;
    const awk_input_buf_t *ibuf;
    const awk_output_buf_t *obuf;

    //GET FILE DESCRIPTOR FOR CURRENT INPUT FILE
        api_result = api->api_get_file(ext_id, NULL, 0, "<", 0, &ibuf, &obuf);
    if (api_result == awk_false) {
        make_number(-1.0, result);
    } else {
        //GET OFFSET OF CURRENT FILE ACCORDING TO OS
            off_t position = lseek(ibuf->fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        make_number(position, result);
    }
    return result;
}

/* init_lseek */
static awk_bool_t 
init_lseek(void)
{
    int     errors = 0;
    return errors == 0;
}

static awk_ext_func_t func_table[] = {
    {"lseek", do_lseek, 0, 0, awk_false, NULL},
};

/* define the dl_load function using the boilerplate macro */
dl_load_func(func_table, lseek, "")
```