How to call user defined gawk functions from a gawk c extension
I am trying to create a gawk extension that adds the ability to register signal handlers for specific signals in gawk which currently there is no built in way to do. After reading the gawk documentation on extensions I am currently able to define c functions which are accessible from the gawk code. I need a way for a user to be able to pass possibly the name of the gawk function to the extension function that registers signal handlers and have this gawk function be called when that signal is received. I have not yet found a way to call user defined gawk functions from this extension. The extension api does provide a way to access the gawk symbol table and modify variables but I have not found a way to call gawk functions from the extension.
Here is the code that I have which creates a function that is callable from gawk called signal that currently just returns the number 1:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include <gawkapi.h>

static const gawk_api_t *api;
static awk_ext_id_t *ext_id;
static const char *ext_version = NULL;
static awk_bool_t (*init_func)(void) = NULL;

int plugin_is_GPL_compatible;

static awk_value_t* do_signal(int nargs, awk_value_t *result, struct awk_ext_func *unused) {
    return make_number(1, result);
}

static awk_ext_func_t func_table[] = {
    { "signal", do_signal, 1, 0, awk_false, NULL }
};

dl_load_func(func_table, some_name, "")


I've read through the entire gawk section about gawk extensions. I have not found a way to do this but maybe I am missing something.

Congratualtions on asking the first gawk-extension question! (+1 just for that)

You might want to email "help dash gawk at gnu dot org" or post a question in comp.lang.awk on usenet where gawk providers, people who've written gawk extensions, and awk experts hang out.

++, might not be useful, but found one example on how to use a user derived gawk extension here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73356712/5291015

As far as I understand the extensions and the API I would answer no, there is no way to call a gawk function from your extension. Some sentences in the documentation could make you believe it is, because they mention a two-ways communication between gawk and the extensions, but the way your are interested in is limited to a predefined set of internal gawk functions. Considering the number and variety of predefined gawk functions, not mentioning the user-defined functions, I do not even imagine what this part of the API (and its documentation) would look like.
